# OMP CRITICAL in OpenMP

Tags: fortran, openmp

What does this mean in FORTRAN?

```
C$OMP CRITICAL (UNNAMED)
```

And

```
C$OMP END CRITICAL (UNNAMED)
```

Doesn't a line with `C` mean that is a comment? But apparently when I remove this line, it doesn't work. What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an OpenMP directive in Fortran, specifically in fixed-form. In your case, the section is called `UNNAMED`. To cite from the [documentation](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/openMP/#CRITICAL), the critical section

> specifies a region of code that must be executed by only one thread at a time.

For fixed-form Fortran, OpenMP directives are prefixed with `C$OMP`, for free form it is `!$OMP`. 
As with all compiler directives in Fortran, OpenMP directives need to be realized as comments in case your compiler does not understand them.

Critical sections are usually used to avoid deadlocks or race conditions. This is probably the case here, as your code breaks if you remove the directives.

Comment: So any code in between these two statements are run by only a single thread? Thank you

Comment: In fixed-form sources, all of `c$omp`, `!$omp`, and `*$omp` starting at column 1 are accepted as OpenMP sentinels.